# Restore deleted Mysql Directory in linux

Tags: mysql, restore

My MySQL directory has been deleted from  directory /root/var/ by mistake, we need to restore it, Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you have backups?

Comment: backup was in same directory..

Comment: Then it seems unlikely that you'll be able to get your data back. You might be able to send it to a data recovery company, but they are generally expensive, and can't guarantee success.

Comment: check my answer there before you do anything !